# Access all camera lenses with default camera intent in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camera-intent

**Background:**

Since the evolution of modern camera hardware, manufacturers from different mobile company started to integrate multiple camera sensors. There could be a scenario where we want to access a specific lens for image processing.

**The challenge:**

I am looking for a way to manually choose between the available camera lenses with Android's default **camera intent** or **Camera2** API. From the official documentation, we can use the following code to open the native camera app and request for an image capture:

```
val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST)
```

However this limits the number of options especially the freedom of choosing between the camera lenses. Here is the preview for default camera view with camera intent:

[image]

However if I launch the native app there's some additional options including the option for choosing **48MP** lens.

[image]

Is there any way to include the **48MP** lens along with other settings in camera intent? Can we use the **Camera2** API to manually access the camera lens programmatically? The solution could be from a 3rd party library/tool too.

Answer (score 2):

> Here is the preview for default camera view with camera intent

There is no single "default camera view".

There are over 26,000 Android device models. There are hundreds of pre-installed camera apps across those device models, and hundreds more that users might install. Your "camera intent" could bring up any of those hundreds of apps.

> However if I launch the native app

There is no single "native app".

> Is there any way to include the 48MP lens along with other settings in camera intent?

No, sorry.

> Can we use the Camera2 API to manually access the camera lens programmatically?

Probably, though the details will depend on the device model. Just because a device has extra lenses does not mean that the manufacturer has to make those lenses available to third-party developers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> Yes

you can access 48mp or any available camera in the Device.

**How?**

1. Create own camera wrapper class which can use device camera and capture photo & Videos
2. You can use Android [Multicamera API](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/multi-camera) and access any camera using `CAMERA ID`

For More Information about this please check out this article [android officials](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/getting-the-most-from-the-new-multi-camera-api-5155fb3d77d9)